# How can I receive results from a Service "later on"?

Tags: android

I have an `IntentService` for downloading files in the background. All it does is download a file and stash it on disk. The App flow involves starting bunch of these download tasks through this service through one Activity and a bit later on, retrieving these downloads through another Activity. For retrieval, I shall be facilitating the download Id and a location of the download to the receiver.

When it comes to retrieval, I am ready to busy-wait until all the downloads have completed because I will be depending on them for moving on further. That is fine except I have found no way to facilitate the following:

A mechanism where I am able to busy-wait for these downloads(like until count of these downloads at the receiver doesn't equal to the total count of downloads). How do I deliver these downloads?

**Note:** Broadcasting doesn't seem to be the solution as what will I do with these downloads until I don't have the Activity that doesn't actually require these downloads?

Comment: You can use [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus).

Comment: Just to clarify, you are doing all downloads in one IntentService and you'll know when all downloads are retrieved? Where do you want to deliver your downloaded data, to the caller class or somewhere else?

Comment: @PeppermintPaddy : Somewhere else - some other Activity shall be retrieving these later when it comes to existence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion there are multiple ways to achieve this. One way would be the already suggested

1) **EventBus Sticky**

[EventBus Sticky](http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/documentation/configuration/sticky-events/) technic, but this needs a new library that increases your App size. I would recommend this approach if you use it multiple times and not just once. An additional plus to [EventBus](http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/documentation/) is that it takes care of [multithreading](http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/documentation/delivery-threads-threadmode/) in an easy manner.

2) **Only SharedPreferences**

Use [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences.html) to keep track of what has been downloaded and if it's finished already when you are starting the 'Show'-Activity. This approach is somehow limited to a certain amount that you can save. You probably should use that if you don't have to save a lot of file paths and you don't need to keep track of older data.

3) **Database and SharedPreferences**

Use a database like [Room](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html) to save file paths and associate it with an integer as a serial. This integer could be used to describe groups of downloads. And every file path can be later on fetched with the appropriate download group number. You'll want this approach if you also want to show older download groups. In that case the groups 'serial'-integer and 'has finished'-boolean can be saved in [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences.html) and checked when 'Show'-Activity is created.

4) **Custom Controller Singleton**

Build a Controller class that is a Singleton and is attached to your Application. It can be retrieved in your Activities and your IntentService by

`((MyApplication) getApplicationContext()).getDownloadController()`

and it can be observing the downloading process.

...

There are multiple ways I can think of e.g. a [RxJava](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/RxJava/article.html) approach just to name it ;)

Hope you got a little overview of the possibilities.

Comment: I ended up going for EventBus. It has certain constraints that are not in Rx but its learning curve is literally 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right I think you can use the 
[Greenrobot EventBus sticky-events](http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/documentation/configuration/sticky-events/) Technic.

In short, the `Service` can propagate a sticky-event when all download are done. 
If you now maybe 5 minutes later start your `Activity` that show the downloads, this `Activity` if it´s listening for this sticky-event, will get the now 5 minute old message.

Hope it helps